# Accessing a variable outside of jquery.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

This is becoming very frustrating so I'm hoping someone is able to help. I am not a great JavaScript or JQuery developer (more of back-end guy) but I've searched high and low for a solution to this and nothing seems to help. This is a simplified version of my problem...

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
fooey = 'baaa';

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

fooey = 'New value';     

});

alert("value: " + fooey);  // I need this to be 'New value'

</script>
```

How can I change the fooey variable inside the JQuery block then access this new value from outside of the JQuery block. So I'm expecting the alert popup to show 'New value' not 'baaa'.

Comment: Can you include alert inside jquery ready function?

Comment: your code is correct, but what is happening here is your alert is getting executed before the document.ready function. if you check the fooey value in console, it should be "New Value"

Comment: Reading between the lines you might think everything jQuery-related must be inside a document.ready block, but that's not the case (and if you do need it, there's no reason not to have "normal" JavaScript outside it.)

Comment: window.fooey is 'New value', the issue is delay of document loaded to browser .. may you are calling your function before document is ready !

Comment: Try body onload, <body onload="getNewValue();"> and inside script tag function getNewValue(){
   alert("value: " + fooey);
 }

Answer (score 3):

You code works but it runs in the following order:

1. fooey = 'baaa';
2. set jQuery(document).ready
3. alert("value: " + fooey);
4. run jQuery(document).ready

This is happening because the JavaScript is run before `document` is ready (and the jQuery event triggers). So provided that you use `fooey` before `document` is ready it should be set to `'New value'`. If you need to use it when *the DOM is ready*, then use it at the end of your `$(document).ready` function.

**Explanation**

Upon loading a webpage, the JavaScript within the page is run. This goes through the code (setting and alerting the value of `fooey`), sets up any events like `.onclick`, `window.onresize` or `$(document).ready()`, these are called later on when the particular events occur. For `$(document).ready()` it occurs when the DOM (document object model) is ready to be worked on.

From [jQuery API - ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received.

Comment: +1 While this is the correct answer explaining the actual _problem_ with the code, and you wre first, I'd really love it if you could elaborate a bit more about how JavaScript's asynchronous nature behaves in this case, and maybe format as a list instead of a code/quote block

Comment: Thank you for this - I thought the problem was a scoping issue :( So clearly it's more of a 'items loading order' issue. This helped a lot; thank you.

Comment: @user2181809 remember to upvote and accept the answer by hitting the tick :)

Answer (score 1):

Define your alert inside ready function and the reason is alert executed before `document.ready` function.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    fooey = 'baaa';
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        fooey = 'New value';     
        alert("value: " + fooey);  // I need this to be 'New value'     
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The trouble is although I am using alert for demonstrating this problem the value is actually needed by JavaScript further down the line. This is why the alert box is outside of the JQuery block.

Answer (score 1):

**javascript** :

```
var foo;
        $(function() {   
           // this is your jquery.ready() function. I have write it in another way
           foo = 'val1'
           alert(foo);
        });

      function fun(){
        foo = 'val2';
        alert(foo);
      }
      function fun2(){
        alert(foo);
      }
```

**HTML code** :

```
   <input type="button" id="b1" value="b1" onclick="fun()" >
   <input type="button" id="b2" value="b2" onclick="fun2()">
```

Now here foo becomes `a global variable`  and the value of `foo` on `page loading` is `val1`.

If you click to button `b1` then it's value becomes `val2`. You can check this value by clicking on button `b2`.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the ready clause is to wait until the document is wholly ready before doing anything. By adding code outside of that event it will be loaded (maybe) before the ready event.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

// executed when browser interprets this line
fooey = 'baaa';  // (1st to be executed)

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// executed after few seconds , when DOM is ready.   (3rd one to be executed)
 fooey = 'New value';     

});


// executed when browser interprets this line (2nd one to be executed)
alert("value: " + fooey);  

</script>
```

At last fooey value is `New value` **but not when you are alerting it**

You can wait until DOM is ready like this.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

fooey = 'baaa';   

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 fooey = 'New value';     

});

var interval = setInterval(function () {
   if ( jQuery.isReady ) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      alert("value: " + fooey);

   }   
},10)
</script>
```

Comment: Jashwant; Thank you very much for the comprehensive reply and solution. This certainly seems to do the trick.

Comment: Why the interval, wouldn't it be easier to just use another document.ready block?

Comment: Yes, I have explained him everything. Other answers are also here asking him to use `document.ready` block. I am just suggesting  solution keeping his logic :)